# Why when setting the duration to 0 and then back to 1 or any value above 0 the fading is not continue?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm implementing a fading effect for my game. I can change the duration to `0.1` (or `1`, `5`, or `10`). But if I change the duration to `0` and the fading stops, then when I change back the duration to any value above `0` the fading does not resume. I tried it on the automatic mode when `isAutomatic` is `true`. I can't figure out why after setting it to `0` and back to `1`, the fading is not continuing.

Here's my current implementation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public bool isAutomatic = false;

    private bool automatic = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            Fade();
        }

        if (isAutomatic && automatic)
        {
            Fade();

            automatic = false;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj,
        Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            yield return null;
        }

        automatic = true;
    }

    private void Fade()
    {
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

        if (scaleUp)
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
        }

        else
        {
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: try walking through the lines of code in the ScaleOverTime coroutine one by one, pretending you're the CPU deciding what to do when duration = 0. Where do you end up when you do this?

Comment: @DMGregory if duration is 0 then counter will never be less then duration and therefore it will never enter and never reach to the yield return null; so the coroutine stop and never continue.

Comment: Don't ask me: I am not the arbiter of whether your code is correct. Run your code and observe the outcome. You can do this far faster than waiting for a stranger on the Internet to get back to you.

Comment: Do you get an exception in your Unity console? Perhaps something hinting that you get a division by zero? When you get an unhandled exception in a coroutine, then that coroutine will crash.

Answer (score 0):

For first situation, setting your `duration = 0` will not enter this loop:

```
        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            yield return null;
        }
```

Hence, object not fading.

Second situation, as for you changing your `duration` from 0 to 1 in runtime, the line `scaleUp = !scaleUp;` is setting `scaleUp = true` at 0, even though the object didn't scale up, now when you increase the duration from 0 to t seconds ( assuming t > 0) , it will again call the  `scaleUp = !scaleUp;` that in return turns `scaleUp = false`, hence the code executing this line

```
scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
```

i.e. going from `objectToScale.transform.localScale` to `minSize` which is the same as `objectToScale.transform.localScale` as set in the `Start()` function.